# How to get useNavigate to push only if the new URI is different from the current?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

There is a button on my App that calls `useNavigate` to change the URI location. I notice that it pushes the URI when pressed repeatedly.

How to get it to only push if the new URI is different from the current URI?

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
<div onClick={() => navigate("/home")}>
  Button
</div>
```

The problem with the code above is that each time the `div` is clicked, `/home` is pushed to the URI history stack even if the current location is `/home`. So that if the user press the back button it would seem to have no effect.

Comment: Look at the uri before you modify it. Your navigator library will have docs on how to do that, or use window.location.href

Comment: What is `navigate`? Please actually include a [mcve] with the relevant code you are having an issue using or working with.

Comment: I have made edits. It is actually `useNavigate` of `react-router-dom` v6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the target path against the current `location.pathname` and only issue the imperative navigation if not already on the same path.

Example:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();


<button
  onClick={() => {
    if (pathname !== "/home") {
      navigate("/home");
    } else {
      console.log("Already Home");
    }
  }}
>
  Go Home
</button>
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-usenavigate-to-push-only-if-the-new-uri-is-different-from-the-current]